# MySQL sales daily report

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello guys I'm creating a daily report. I'm a beginner on my MySQL. 
I want to generate this kind of data. 
I have a table in my phpmyadmin with this structure

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Item_desc<th>
        <th>Total_price<th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Branch</th>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Bottle</td>
        <td>100 </td>
        <td>10 </td>
        <td>June 26,2016 </td>
        <td>Rizal</td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bottle</td>
        <td>120 </td>
        <td>12 </td>
        <td>June 26,2016 </td>
        <td>Rizal</td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Bottle</td>
        <td>100 </td>
        <td>10 </td>
        <td>June 26,2016 </td>
        <td>Rizal</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I'm getting only 1 record. I want to get all of that records with the sum of total_price and quantity. This is my current query. Thank you.

```
$query= $this->db->select('*,SUM(total_price),SUM(quantity)')->from('sales')->where('branch',$_SESSION['branch'])->where('date',$from)->get();
```

Comment: yes but only 1 record.

Comment: `date` is reserved in mysql

Comment: Part of the problem is in what you didn't show us, how you're looping over results.

Comment: @Abdulla *"date is reserved in mysql"* - who says? Funny, last time I saw, there was no `(R)` next to it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- I only get this result Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [item_desc] => Bottle [total_price] => 400.00 [quantity] => 55 [branch] => Rizal  [date_sold] => June 26,2016 [price] => 2200.00 ) )

Comment: where and how are you displayiing those results? Usually, a `while` loop suffices. I can't tell how you're using the method used and if the session was started. There isn't much I can do to help. The other guy seems to have left the question/answer.

Comment: print_r() @Fred-ii-

Comment: `print_r()` and a `while` loop are two different animals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->load->library('session');
$branch = $this->session->userdata('branch');

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *,SUM(total_price) AS price,SUM(quantity) As quantity
                            FROM sales 
                            WHERE branch = '$branch' AND WHERE date = '$from' ");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: *"Keep note date is reserved id MySQL."* -  Is it not. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html it is a "keyword", not a "reserved" word. Let's lose that misconception.

Comment: I change my query to this
$query= $this->db->select('*,SUM(total_price) as price ,SUM(quantity) as quantity')->from('sales')->where('branch',$_SESSION['branch'])->where('date_sold',$from)->get();

Comment: @JonasDulay so ther may be one data set. Is date condition is correct?? = or > ??

Comment: @JonasDulay If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)